# Is it possible to modify the Notification and Alert Settings for all users on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ms-office-communicator

We are testing moving users to from XP to windows 7. One of the first complaints we got is that the default behavior for Communicator 2007 doesn't show the "pop-up" notifications when you first receive a message. This can be fixed by running Communicator.exe in windows vista compatibility mode, or in the notification customization area, you select show icon and notifications.

My question is, can I set communicator to show icon and notifications by default? We are deploying using MDT 2010 and copying profiles from xp with USMT 4.0